# Database stored image path gives conflicts in subdirectories

Tags: php, image

I stored my image path in database as follows.

```
  ../../products/category/subcategory/img/filename
```

When I access the img from www.site.com/product.php? Id=1

I cannot access the image from the originally saved path

How to find the image path from the current directory

Comment: When I access the image from the sites root folder it will move up two folders.

Comment: Store your images in the directory with ` ../../products/category/subcategory/img/filename` but save the image in database with `products/category/subcategory/img/filename`. This way you can access the image with `www.site.com/{database_image_path}`
like: `www.site.com/products/category/subcategory/img/filename`

Comment: What should I do if I need to access the image from www.site.com/category/subcategory/index.php . I want to list all the images of sub directories. @VikasArora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment...

To access the images in any file, just append the image path with the root url. Say you have stored all your images in a folder `images` and its location is `http://www.example.com/images/file.jpg` and you are storing the path in database like this: `images/file.jpg`, then to access this image anywhere just combine the root url which is `http://www.example.com` with the image database path. So it will become complete path of image and can be accessed.

Example code:

```
<?php  
$root_url = "http://www.example.com";
$image_url = "/images/file.jpg";
?>
<img src="<?php echo $root_url.$image_url; ?>" >
```

Of course, onsider this as an example only, for reference.